# RecyclerView inside a ViewPager is empty when I leave it in the background for a long time and come back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I put a RecyclerView inside a ViewPager. When I open my application it works normally. When I turn the screen it works normally. If I minimize the application and after a few minutes I go back to it everything works correctly. However, when I leave it in the background for a long time and come back, all pages that were already loaded, three, are empty. I can interact normally with the ViewPager and if I roll to one side I get into a RecyclerView showing content. If I go far enough to cause the loaded lists to be destroyed when I get back they are normal. The problem is the moment the application comes back and there is nothing on the pages that had already been loaded. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how do I resolve it?

So, here is some code:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    db = new VirtualDataBase(this);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedTab);
}
```

and then the Fragment:

```
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setSectionId(sectionNumber);
        return fragment;
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            rootView.invalidate();
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        meusItems= new MeusItems();

        myDataset = new ArrayList<>();

        db = new VirtualDataBase(getContext());
        list1 = db.getList1();

        if (sectionId == 1) {
            mAdapter = new MainList1Adapter(list1, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else if (sectionId == 2) {
            myDataset = meusItems.getFirstPart();
            mAdapter = new MainAdapter(myDataset, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else if (sectionId == 3) {
            myDataset = meusItems.getSecondPart();
            mAdapter = new MainAdapter(myDataset, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                new DividerItemDecoration(rootView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        return rootView;
    }
```

and the PagerAdapter, just the default implementation:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

These are all the relevant methods I'm using to create the screens.

Comment: You give an excellent description of your problem, but there is more than one way to implement a ViewPager. So I've (almost) no idea what could be causing this behaviour. Please consider posting enough code so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry @0X0nosugar, I just updated the question and added some code. Is that enough?

Comment: Much better :) My first thought was: you are very likely using a retained Fragment, because I have experienced a similar behaviour in one of my apps. So it's good to see that this is the case. Now I don't want to write an answer like "well, that's what happens when you use retained Fragments" and without any suggestion how to fix the problem. I'd like to set up a sample based on your code and to get back to you with a tested solution, but this will take a while.

Comment: Adding an offscreen page limit to your view pager should enable you to have that many number of fragments at any time. This may be what's required.

Comment: @AlokOmkar I've already tried using the offscreen page limit on my view pager to solve this problem but it did not work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks 0X0nosugar, knowing that the problem might be in using the retained fragment I'll try to figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Maybe this (older but not completely outdated) [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) by Alex J. Lockwood is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the article @0X0nosugar, after reading it I realized there was no need to use retained Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that android is destroying the view of your fragments and, when you come back, android is recreating those views without destroy the fragment itself.

Probably (without code is hard to guess), you are creating the view of your fragments in `onCreate` instead of `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

After a while I discovered the problem. In the application there is a Fragment that depending on its position presents different data. I was using `sectionId` to set what would be shown on each of the ViewPager pages:

```
if (sectionId == 1) {
    mAdapter = new MainList1Adapter(list1, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else if (sectionId == 2) {
    myDataset = meusItems.getFirstPart();
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(myDataset, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else if (sectionId == 3) {
    myDataset = meusItems.getSecondPart();
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(myDataset, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

What happened was that when the app stayed too long in the background and then it was reopened **`sectionId` was equal to 0**. To solve the problem I saved the value of `sectionId` using `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putInt("sectionId", sectionId);
 }
```

and retrieve this value in `onCreateView`:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
    sectionId = savedInstanceState.getInt("sectionId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** instead. It is a better option if there is a large number of child Fragments. Second, you are probably loading too many views in your fragment.

Replace:-

```
public class YourAdapterName extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

with this:-

```
public class YourAdapterName extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```